# Should I write selectors from right to left?

Tags: css, web

I was wondering since browsers parse a CSS document from right to left would it be better to write a selector like this:

```
a li #MainContent { }
```

instead of like this:

```
#MainContent li a { }
```

So that the browser can eliminate a selector that does match an element more quickly? Does this make any sense or am I misunderstanding? Thanks for any insight!

Comment: The first selector has no sense .... Read the basic of CSS selectors

Comment: I always use #id li a because it makes more sense and easy to read.

Comment: CSS is interpreted LTR, so writing RTL will cause problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put...

1. It depends on the structure of your HTML (DOM)
2. `a li #MainContent` !== `#MainContent li a`

The first is redundant and can be simply replaced with `#MainContent` as `id` is unique. Ultimately it selects the `#MainContent` element. The second selects links which are children of list items which are children of `#MainContent`.

3. In modern browsers, the resolution of selectors in terms of directional performance is negligible, focus on writing concise ones instead

Answer (score 0):

Usually we type to in order to show something inside the parent for example

```
div ul {}
```

this means select the `ul` in the `div` element so there won't be any point in writing it backwards order does matter for css